# connecting javascript to a Web API

Tags: javascript, html, visual-studio-2012, asp.net-web-api

I am new to the web development world and I would like to be able to connect an HTML page to a web api through . and I was really not successful in this.

I followed this tutorial to be able to make this connection : http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/getting-started-with-aspnet-web-api/tutorial-your-first-web-api

All I need is to send some inputs from an HTML page to a web api that takes these parameters and returns an object

I am using this code

```
$.getJSON("api/GeneratorController/setparameters/"+firstparameter+"/"+secondparameter+"/"+thirdparameter+"/"+fourthparameter+"/"+fifthparameter+"/"+sixthparameter,
function (data) {
   alert(data); //never comes here
}).fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, err) {
   alert("All checks are correct, image was not generated. jqXHR = " + jqXHR.valueOf() + " textStatus=" + textStatus + " Error" + err);
});
```

it always goes into the fail portion , I attached the alert message that comes out of it

[image: Error Message]

Any Reason why it is doing this ?

@smartmeta (I changed the typo , thanks) I followed your advice and here is the output of the alert (as expected , values that I have inserted are displayed):
[image]

Comment: The error "not found" means the url you are passing doesn't exist, meaning the webapi doesn't have a route that matches what your passing.  You should probably pass your parameters as either a query string or in the body.

Comment: @BenFelda thanks for your response. Again I am bran new in this field , can you guide me to a guide to show me how to do that , in my controller my code is something like this:
public int setparameters(the 6 parameters)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found what was the problem with my code

Two things :

1- I shouldn't use the word "Controller" when I call my API ,it should be `api/Generator/...`

2- the function name needs to start with "get" and not "set" since it "gets" the return value from the api

Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 1):

Your url needs to start with your domain, not `'api/generatorcontroller/...'`.  If you are developing locally, something like `http://localhost:[port]/api/generatorController/...`.

Also, webApi maps to url verbs, (get, post, put, delete..), not functions like setparameters, unless you have a [name=setparameters] above your get() function.

Also, I am pretty sure you don't have a route setup to handle the url with all those parameters.  What you want to look at, as it seems your using jQuery, is [jQuery.get](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/) documentation.  The second example near the bottom shows where to place parameters.  WebAPI will check for them in the body if they are not in the query string. so it would end up looking like:

`$.getJSON("http://"+window.location.host+"/api/GeneratorController/setparameters", {parameter1: parameter1, parameter2:parameter2 ...});`

Answer (score 0):

Well, the first thing to check is to make sure that your server-side function is returning the values you expect. You can do this with Chrome's developer tools or with the Firebug Firefox extension, and I think IE10 has something equivalent, too. Go to the "net" tab, find the request corresponding to your API call, and take a look at what the server responded with.

Comment: Thanks for your response , nothing is on the server yet , everything is still local on my machine , does it make any difference?

Comment: Well, there's your problem. The error message you're getting is just your browser saying "I tried to talk to the server, but I didn't hear anything back". Which, since you don't have a server, is exactly what you should expect.

Comment: Well, unless you've got a web server running locally on your machine that you're using for development, in which case, if you've got it set up properly, it should work the same way a remote web server would.

Comment: thank you for your response

I thought that the creation of a "localhost" session by VS2012 is sufficient for such senarios no ?

Comment: Not sure; I've never used VS2012. Sounds like what you need, though. In that case, we're back to looking at what your local server is sending to your browser, which, as Ben Felda points out, is likely a 404 error.

Answer (score 0):

Please add the line

```
  alert("api/GeneratorController/setparameters/"+firstparemeter+"/"+secondparameter+"/"+thirdparameter+"/"+fourthparameter+"/"+fifthparameter+"/"+sixthparameter)
```

Then call your script and take the output of the alert into a browser. Then check if your application Handels that route.

By the way I think you have a typo. I guess it should be firstparameter.

I assume you would like to do

```
"api/GeneratorController?foo=Bar
```

But when you are new to this, I would suggest that you first try the example like it is. And After that you can start changing setails.

Comment: I assume you would like to pass some parameters.

Comment: Yes I defenetly need to pass parameters , can you show me how to pass multiple parameters?

Comment: I would suggest that you first try your mentioned example like it is. And After that you can start changing setails.

Comment: So I found already one issue : I had to remove the word "Controller". I created a dummy function that takes a string and returns it in .NET and it works!  now I need to find out why it doesn t like taking more than one parameter ... I tried "api/Generator?foo=Bar&foo2=bar2 but it doesn t work , what should I change it to ?